# How should I store sprouts after they have sprouted in glass?

Tags: containers

How should I store sprouts after they have sprouted in glass? I choose not to use plastic for environmental concerns.

Comment: what kind of sprouts?

Comment: Welcome to the group outofcash!  Would you please add a picture or two of your sprouts? Also, are they sprouted seeds or little plants? What's your plan for them? We need those details so we can help you better. You can press this [edit] and add them in. Have a look around our [help] to see how our system works. [ask] is a good place to start. If you have any questions about the site, leave a comment here and someone will help you!  Have fun!

Comment: Although I think this question may be on topic, it should be well-suited to cooking.stackexchange.com, if you don't get the desired answer(s) here.